# Variables that cannot be generalized

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to create Hashtable with value of Hashtable, like this:

```
let map = ((Hashtbl.create 100) : ((int, (_,int) Hashtbl.t) Hashtbl.t ));;
```

but unfortunately casting the type doesn't help me and compiler said: 
"Batteries.Hashtbl.t, contains type variables that cannot be generalized". How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You apparently want the keys of your contained hash tables to be of any type. But this isn't possible, OCaml is a strongly typed language.

If you know the types in advance you can create a variant type, which collects together tagged values of different types and makes one type out of them.

One way to do this might be as follows, where each internal hash table has a single consistent key type.

```
type intstrHT = IntHT of (int, int) Hashtbl.t |
                StrHT of (string, int) Hashtbl.t

let map : (int, intstrHT) Hashtbl.t = Hashtbl.create 100
```

Another possibility is that you want different types of keys in the same hash table:

```
type intstr = Int of int | Str of string

let map : (int, (intstr, int) Hashtbl.t) Hashtbl.t = Hashtbl.create 100
```

**Update**

You can't have a hash table with an unspecified key type. Note the following session:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.02.1

# let map : (_, int) Hashtbl.t = Hashtbl.create 100;;
val map : ('_a, int) Hashtbl.t = <abstr>
# Hashtbl.add map "yes" 15;;
- : unit = ()
# Hashtbl.add map 44 88;;
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
         string
# map;;
- : (string, int) Hashtbl.t = <abstr>
```

You can declare the type of the key as "unspecified," but this just means it will be figured out later. You still just get to have one type of key. In the above, the compiler figures out that your key type is `string`.

If the compiler can't figure out the type of your key by the end of the module, you get the same "cannot be generalized" error that you saw.

```
$ cat gk.ml
let map : (_, int) Hashtbl.t = Hashtbl.create 100
$ ocamlc -c gk.ml
File "gk.ml", line 1, characters 31-49:
Error: The type of this expression, ('_a, int) Hashtbl.t,
       contains type variables that cannot be generalized
```

**Update 2**

You can also declare a *function* that takes values of different types. Functions can be polymorphic, but specific containers can't be.

```
# let f (x: (_, int) Hashtbl.t) y = Hashtbl.find x y;;
val f : ('a, int) Hashtbl.t -> 'a -> int = <fun>
```

This function can accept hash tables with different key types. But no single hash table can have more than one key type.

Comment: but why ocamlc says nothing wrong with construction like this: "let foo (map1 : (_, int) Hashtbl.t)  = ... "

Comment: This just says you're going to pick your key type later. It doesn't allow more than one key type. (See update.)